# spring-boot 2.5.1 - Config data location 'consul:' cannot be found

Tags: spring-boot

We are up the spring-boot version from 2.4.2 to 2.5.1 and catch problem when run app:

```java
13:03:51.052 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationNotFoundException: Config data location 'consul:' cannot be found
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.checkMandatoryLocations(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.applyToEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:144)
    at ru.tinkoff.bpm.flexconsumer.FlexConsumerApplicationKt.main(FlexConsumerApplication.kt:19)
```

The problem sounds like this: In the loader class ConfigDataLocationResolvers a check has been added-whether to load the settings, if they relate to a specific profile. (on the first screen)
[1st screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dZhS.png)

But in the implementation of loading settings from the consul, there is such an implementation(the ConsulConfigDataLocationResolver class) that settings that do not relate to some profile are not loaded at all
[2nd screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdlQZ.png)

How "force" configuration loading?

application-production.yml

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - 'consul:'
      - 'vault://'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have reported this on the official Spring Boot Gitter channel as well as the Spring Boot issue tracker - [it's been accepted as a regression there](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26960) and will be fixed in due course.

Right now the issue is scheduled to be fixed in 2.4.x, meaning both 2.4.x and 2.5.x releases will contain the fix when it's ready.